# Using loop to create dataframe from extracted components from many objects in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

## Background Information

I have been running mediation analysis using the `mediate` function available in the [R Mediation Packag](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/mediation.pdf)e by Tingley et. al. I have run this package on a series of iterations of regressions, and it has left me with approximately 50 mediation objects.

Unfortunately, the `mediation` package does not seem to have an easy way to export the summaries of these objects, and it is not supported by `stargazer`. Therefore, I figured that I would try to extract the desired information from these objects myself and package them into a data frame.

## What I want to do

I want to extract specific components from each mediation object and insert them as a row into a new data frame. This is what I want the data to look like:

```
MEDIATION     ACME    ACME 95H    ACME95L   ACMEP   ...   N.OBS
Mediation 1   0.809   1.201       0.756     0.02    ...   3154
Mediation 2   0.765   0.829       0.711     0.05    ...   3154
Mediation 3   0.050   0.159      -0.056     0.76    ...   3154
```

I have searched through the mediation objects and found the corresponding components for each of the items that I would like to extract. My thinking was that I would use a loop to generate a dataset that would assign each mediation object a single row, and would array the specified data in wide form.

## Reproducible Example

Below is a reproducible version of running the basic mediation. For the sake of example, I use the `swiss` data, which are pre-packaged with R.

```
# Use `swiss` data
summary(swiss)

# use `mediation` package
library(mediation)

# Run the regression for the IV effect on mediator
med.m <- lm(Catholic ~ Education, data = swiss)

# Run the regression for the full model, including mediator
med.y <- lm(Infant.Mortality ~ Education + Catholic, data = swiss)

# Run the mediation analysis, with the IV set as "Education and the mediator set as "Catholic"
Mediation.1<- mediate(med.m, med.y, sims = 1000, treat = "Education", mediator = "Catholic")

# Inspect the Mediation
summary(medsummary)
```

Here is what I tried to do when extracting the components of the mediation object:

```
# Create a list of the mediations
mediations <- c("Mediation.1", "Mediation.2", "Mediation.3", ..., "Mediation 50")

# Create an empty data frame
med.df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 51, ncol = 20))

# Loop through data and extract components
for (c in seq(1:51)){
    for (i in mediations){
        med.df[c,] <- c("i", i[[1]]1, i[[3]][1], i[[3]][2], i[[5]][1], [[92]])
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this just results in the data frame looking like this:

```
1  i Mediation.1     i Mediation.1    i Mediation.1    i Mediation.1    i Mediation.1
2  i Mediation.1     i Mediation.1    i Mediation.1    i Mediation.1    i Mediation.1
3  i Mediation.1     i Mediation.1    i Mediation.1    i Mediation.1    i Mediation.1
```

Would someone be willing to help me understand what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems that there are several issues with your code. Can you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi @Alex, I am not sure that I quite understand. I did post my code. Aside from posting the contents of one of the mediation objects, I don't know what else to post.

Comment: Examples: your first line (`mediations <- ...`) appears to be a placeholder, not real code (it doesn't work); your indexing within the inner `for` loop is inconsistent and equally incorrect. It would help to provide *input data* that can be used with *sample code* to run functions from the `mediation` package, get the output, and try to replicate what you are attempting to create. Please edit your question using these references: [help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you make up some sample data which are as minimal as possible but also provides everything needed for others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have now included a reproducible example!

Comment: If you look on pg.15 of your link (the module's documentation), you will see all items of the `mediate()` function. Some are vectors themselves of multiple values which cannot fill a cell of a matrix/dataframe. Scalar values like `nobs` would be best. So, you need to decide what data pts. to keep for df.

Comment: There are some problems in your example. I notice `i[[1]]1` in the for loop - should the 1 be on the end? Also in the loop is `[[92]]`. Should there be an `i` in front of this?
Aside, using `c` as a variable in your for loop is not a great idea, because `c()` is a function.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea! If you have a bunch of bunch of objects with similar names floating in your environment, specifying them with strings rather than hardcoding something in is a good idea. I don't know the specifics of the `mediation` package, so I'm going to assume that:

- You have fifty regression objects in your environment named `Mediation.n`, where `n` is a number in the range 1:50, and
- You want to save the properties `property1`, `property2` and `property3` of these objects to the data frame (I don't know specifically what you want to save, but I'm going to assume that you know how to access those properties through `$property1` or `[['property1']]` syntax).

Here's my version:

```
# here's a shorter way to get your variable names together
med.names = paste('Mediations', 1:5, sep = '.')

# results df (no need to preallocate rows!)
# sub other data types (eg. numeric()) for character() to taste
med.df = data.frame(
    name = character(0)
    property1 = character(0),
    property2 = character(0),
    property3 = character(0))

for (med.name.current in med.names)
{
    # med.s is a string: the name of the object
    # we need the object itself
    med.i = get(med.name.current)

    # we're going to glue the current med.df column-wise to
    # another, new df with just one row.
    # it'll have the same col names as the current one!
    med.df = rbind(med.df, data.frame(
        name = med.name.current,
        property1 = med.i$property1,
        property2 = med.i$property2,
        property3 = med.i$property3))
}

# now do whatever you like with med.df!
```

Is this what you're looking for? There are two important bits to note here:

1. If you're going to use strings to specify objects in the environment, you need to give the string to the [`get()`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.1/topics/get) function, which will return the object in question. You can't just plonk the strings together in your code.
2. We tend to think about data frames as being a list of rows, but they're actually a list of columns. So you can't add a row by specifying it with [`c()`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.1/topics/c). Instead, you need to create a new data frame, then join it to the old one column-wise (horizontally, if you will) with [`rbind()`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R6Frame/versions/0.1.0/topics/rbind). (Just FYI, you can also glue a vector or data frame to another vector or data frame row-wise, or vertically, using `cbind()`!)

Finally, as @SimonJackson notes, using the variable name `c` is a great way to prematurely age, as it's already used by the function `c()`, which creates vectors. If you assign to it, you might not be able to use `c()` anymore.

I hope that helps!